# How to limit the transfer of owned objects in Sui move?

Tags: sui

How to limit/restrict/prevent the transfers of owned objects in Sui move?
I want to block a user from sending an object in his/her wallet to make the object soulbound like some of the SuiFrens.
I've have had a look at the [sui::transfer module](https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui/blob/main/crates/sui-framework/packages/sui-framework/sources/transfer.move) code and the [docs](https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui/blob/main/crates/sui-framework/docs/transfer.md) but did not find how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If an object `T` does not have the `store` ability, it cannot be transferred except by code inside the module that declares `T`. A useful pattern is to declare a "custom transfer" function, wrapping `sui::transfer::transfer` and imposing the restrictions inside the function. Here is an example: [examples.sui.io/basics/custom-transfer](https://examples.sui.io/basics/custom-transfer.html)

Credit to Sam Blackshear for answering the question on Telegram